# deserialize class with list of derived types including itself From XML to C#

Tags: c#, recursion, derived-class, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to develop a system to deserialize an XML document used as a settings file. At the moment i have the whole thing working except for one node used for tool layouts and settings. my testing example of the node structurally looks like the following:

```
<ListNode  X="0" Y="0">
    <ValueNode X="0" Y="0">
        <Val1><X>-1400</X><Y>4995</Y><Z>933</Z></Val1>
        <Val2><X>-1.385</X><Y>-.055</Y></Val2>
        <Val3>1</Val3>
    </ValueNode>
    <ListNode X="1" Y="0">
        <ValueNode X="0" Y="0">
            <Val1><X>10</X><Y>-95</Y><Z>3</Z></Val1>
            <Val2><X>4.21</X><Y>-.055</Y></Val2>
            <Val3>32</Val3>
        </ValueNode>
        <ValueNode X="0" Y="1">
            <Val1><X>42</X><Y>49</Y><Z>-6</Z></Val1>
            <Val2><X>6</X><Y>7</Y></Val2>
            <Val3>90</Val3>
        </ValueNode>
    </ListNode>
</ListNode>
```

ListNodes can have any number of child nodes and as shown ListNodes can be a child node, thus making them recursive.In this case ValueNodes will not have child nodes other than those used to represent ints, floats, and vectors.

In my C# application I have the classes these nodes should be deserialized to defined as follows:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ListNode)),
XmlInclude(typeof(ValueNode))]
public class ToolSettings
{
    [XmlAttribute("X")]
    public int X;
    [XmlAttribute("Y")]
    public int Y;
}
[XmlType(TypeName = "ListNode")]
public class ListNode : ToolSettings
{
    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(ListNode)),
    XmlArrayItem(typeof(ValueNode))]
    public List<ToolSettings> ValueNodes;
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "ValueNode")]
public class ValueNode : ToolSettings
{
    [XmlElement("Val1")]
    public Vector3 Val1;
    [XmlElement("Val2")]
    public Vector2 Val2;
    [xmlElement("Val3")]
    public int Val3;
}
```

The Issue i'm having is that I can't get the list member of the ListNode class, "ValueNodes", to be populate. I have tried removing both the XmlInclude and the XmlArray.* attributes, individually and together, due to the potential overlap but the result is the same. I have tried replacing the top level of this node with a list identical to the ValueNodes member and succeeded in populating that but the child ListNode still would not get a populated list.

Comment: In my experience, the best way to troubleshoot this is to set up some in-memory data using the .NET types you've created, and then serialize that.  The difference between the structure of the serialized XML and that of the XML you're trying to deserialize should help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the Quick comment phoog. Following your suggestion the serialized ListNode contains a sub node for the "ValueNodes" list, otherwise it came out correctly. Is there a way to get the serializer to consider the lists content to be the content of the ListNode and not write the "ValueNodes" sub node?

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate post however I was unable to find the Threads resolving the question prior to my post. now that i've seen the answer i've also have been able to find related posts, though not in the same contectxt. again sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit the `XmlArray` attribute.  See the documentation for `XmlElementAttribute` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired result but doing this and replacing XmlArrayItem with XmlElement thx